# Nested preference screens lose theming

Tags: android, preferences, preferencescreen

I have a preference screen for my application and in the manifest I have given it a theme using:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings"
```

However when I nest another preference screen inside this one such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:title="@string/setting_title"
    android:key="...">

    <PreferenceCategory
    android:title="@string/title_themes"
    >

    <PreferenceScreen
    android:title="@string/title_themes_opt"
    >

        <ListPreference
    android:key="Setting_BG"
    android:title="@string/setting_bg"
    android:summary="@string/setting_bg_summary"
    android:entries="@array/bg_titles"
    android:defaultValue="0"
    android:entryValues="@array/bg_values" />
    </PreferenceScreen>

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

The nested preference screen loses the theme of the parent. How can this be prevented? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in android see the [Bug Report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4611&can=1&q=preferencescreen%20theme&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into this problem.

While the suggestion in the bug report is to create your own custom style and set the listview background, we found it easier to create a separate activity for each preference screen.  This allowed us to set the Theme.Light to each screen with no issue.

Not a great fix, but it works.

Comment: How do I go about loading in a separate activity for each preference screen?  Can you point me to an example?

Comment: I'm guessing I have to use addPreferenceFromIntent()  Trying to figure out how to do that now.