# how to make the nested Android PreferenceScreen show in Full Screen(without titlebar in system)

Tags: android, preferencescreen

I have write an PreferenceActivity and it contains nested child PreferenceScreen. the problem is i want made them FullScreen, i've add theme.fullscreen in AndroidManifest and it works, but when i click on one of the sub-item to enter an nested PreferenceScreen, the title bar appears. and now i didn't know how to make the nested full screen too.
and i've look source code for PreferenceScreen to find help. it shows that nested preferenceScreen was showed on an Dialog, and i found the code which new the Dialog in method showDialog.

```
Dialog dialog = mDialog = new Dialog(context, TextUtils.isEmpty(title)
            ? com.android.internal.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar
            : com.android.internal.R.style.Theme);
```

it seems that noway to do that, but i really want to know is anyone can implement this in one PreferenceActivity.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in android see the [Bug Report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4611&can=1&q=preferencescreen%20theme&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

There is a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826334/807434) by using addPreferenceFromIntent().